# Github suddenly failed to connect

Tags: git, github

```
My github suddenly failed to connect 

$ git push
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Tried

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
Hi alinbxSorcerer! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

What's the problem, it works fine for years.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you're on a network blocking port 22.

Setup ssh to always use port 443 for Github from now on:

Add the following to your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Another option is switching to use the `https` repo urls but I find annoying having to type the passwords every now and then.

More info on this: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Comment: indeed just open vpn fix to me as well